# http request to fetch data from database via php in android, different result with using browser

Tags: php, android, mysql, rest, http

I am developing an android application, using PHP to interact with the server. I am using the 000hosting free server, when I move the PHP from local to the server, something wired happened.

This is the result using the phone:
I output the result in Logcat.

```
   Log.d(TAG, "RESULT: " + result);

   D/GetNoteBackupsSummary: RESULT: <br /> 
   System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Why I get `<br />` as the result?

Output from browser:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"nznnznss","content":"kzkzkzkzkz","date":"2018-10-06 23:02:50","backup_time":"2018-10-07 02:48:10"},
 {"id":"2","title":"nznzksks","content":"nsnsnnsksks","date":"2018-10-06 23:02:45","backup_time":"2018-10-07 02:48:10"}, 
  {"id":"3","title":"jzjsjsj","content":"nznzkzkzkz","date":"2018-10-06 23:02:40","backup_time":"2018-10-07 02:48:10"}, 
  {"id":"4","title":"bsjsjsj ","content":"jsjsksk ","date":"2018-10-06 23:02:35","backup_time":"2018-10-07 02:48:10"}]
```

This is the php code:

```
session_start();

// $user_email = $_POST["user_email"];
// $time = $_POST["backup_time"];

$time = "2018-10-07 02:48:10";
$user_email = "ccc@ccc";

if (!$con) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
$result = new \stdClass();

$out_put = array();
$table_name = getBackupUserTableName($user_email);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE backup_time = '".$time."'";
if($query = mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        array_push($out_put, $row);
    }
    print json_encode($out_put);
}else{
    $result -> status = false;
    $result -> error = mysqli_error($con);
    print json_encode($result);
}



mysqli_close ($con);
```

It works very well in local. 
Appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: What happens if you access this with a low-level tool like `curl`? Can you see the actual output and verify that it's 100% JSON?

Comment: The error is in that you are receiving a <br> tag in the response that is breaking the decoding of the json in the android side. 1) When returning json, set the content type header to application/json. 2) Check that the php file doesn't have any non intended html. 3) Not sure if there is any difference but see if you get the same result using echo instead of print.

Comment: I would suggest the error is in your android code. Please post the code you use to fetch the data.

Comment: Thanks you all. I found the error. I was debugging the wrong php file. There was an undefined variable in the php file. Thanks!

Comment: @tadman thank you again, I will change the code using the bind_param